# Threadsafety of a method with multiple db calls

Tags: c#, thread-safety, locking

I just read this SO question [Which design is most preferable: test-create, try-create, create-catch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241866/which-design-is-most-preferable-test-create-try-create-create-catch)

Regarding to the answer, seems devs prefer "Try-Create" pattern, and some of them mentioned the **TryCreate(user, out resultCode)** can be a **threadsafe**, but other patterns not.

Try-Create

```
enum CreateUserResultCode
{
    Success,
    UserAlreadyExists,
    UsernameAlreadyExists
}

if (!TryCreate(user, out resultCode))
{
    switch(resultCode)
    {
        case UserAlreadyExists: act on user exists error;
        case UsernameAlreadyExists: act on username exists error;
    }
}
```

I am thinking if the **tryCreate** method involves multiple db calls what is the proper way to make it thread-safe in a real practice?

Say **tryCreate** will do 2 things:

1. Check if the user name existing in db
2. If the name not existing then create a new one

It is very possible a thread finishes 1 but not 2, another thread start to invoke this method **tryCreate** and also finishes 1, which is a race-condition.

Surely, in **tryCreate** I can add a lock or sth, but it will make the **tryCreate** a hot point. If I have a high-profile website, all new registers have to wait for the lock in **tryCreate**.

What I see from other websites is when you type in your username,it will trigger a ajax call to check if it is existing in current db, then you go to next step to create it.(Not sure if there is a lock been created at this moment.)

Any thoughts about how to implement a proper safe **tryCreate** involving multiple db calls in a real life?

**Updates 1**:
The logic of **TryCreate** can be very complicated and not just 2 db calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread-safety concept doesn't spawn to the databases. So whatever you do on the client side has no effect on the database side, purely because by design database supports multiple concurrent connection from many clients.

Instead use *transactions* to perform several actions as atomic operation on the database end.